# jQuery Animation Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Have a look on this two pictures and tell me if is any chance to create this transition in jQuery. So I have 3 pictures which should be buttons. The thing is it should looks in those shapes like in first picture. On picture touching should to have an transit effect as in the second picture. So the first one should to transit in right side and see the whole picture for 2 seconds and after to open a page. Second picture should to transit in both sides and the third one in the left side.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you can use CSS3 rotations on the left and right polygons to get the effect.

Comment: Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/